# hazelcast topic as a hazelcast-jet source

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I'm trying to get more up to speed with Hazelcast Jet as a processing pipeline and began digging into the Sources documentation a bit more

https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/sources-sinks#sources

I was very surprised to see that Hazelcast [Topics](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.1/manual/html-single/index.html#topic) and [ReliableTopics](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.1/manual/html-single/index.html#reliable-topic) aren't natively supported sources, however Kafka and JmsQueue are supported out of the box. I do see that a hazelcast [reliabletopic is a supported sink](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/sources-sinks#sinks)... which makes me question whether or not I am misunderstanding a topic as a valid source for a pipeline.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazelcast `ITopic` is a non-distributed in-memory facility, and doesn't support exactly-once processing. These are probably some of the reasons Hazelcast hasn't so far offered first-class support for it. Kafka is an example of a persistent, distributed and fault-tolerant facility, which makes it a good match for an architecture where you require the exactly-once consistency level.

On the other hand, you can use the `SourceBuilder` and `SinkBuilder` to implement your own connectors for it. [Here's](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/blob/master/examples/source-sink-builder/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/examples/sinkbuilder/TopicSink.java) an example from our code samples repository.

Comment: ahh, I had missed that ITopic "doesn't support exactly-once processing" from the hazelcast docs... I think I had assumed too much about the 'globalOrderEnabled' flag and attributed 'exactly-once' processing to that too. Makes sense. Thanks!